# Bulk loading timestamp sensitive data HBase

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, hbase

We have a lot of historical data that we need to migrate into HBase. The setup of our HBase is that the (timestamp) versioning is relevant and using some domain knowledge we know at which time the different columns were available. The amount of data is vast so I was wondering what would be a good way of doing this bulk load. Scala or Python is fine, preferably with Spark.

Comment: I do a lot of work with HBase from spark in scala. I have some good implicits and other methods that will get you 90% there. I will post an answer after I generalize it a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

I've published a [gist](https://gist.github.com/travishegner/12cf5542881ca8fac6377cc56c7a7ea1#file-hbase-scala) that gets you most of the way there. I'll reproduce the most relevant method here:

```
def write[TK, TF, TQ, TV](
  tableName: String,
  ds: Dataset[(TK, Map[TF, Map[TQ, TV]])],
  batch: Int = 1000
)(implicit
  fk: TK => HBaseData,
  ff: TF => HBaseData,
  fq: TQ => HBaseData,
  fv: TV => HBaseData
): Unit = {
  ds.foreachPartition(p => {
    val hbase = HBase.getHBase
    val table = hbase.getTable(TableName.valueOf(tableName))
    val puts = ArrayBuffer[Put]()

    p.foreach(r => {
      val put = new Put(r._1)
      r._2.foreach( f => {
        f._2.foreach( q => {
          put.addColumn(f._1, q._1, q._2)
        })
      })

      puts += put
      if (puts.length >= batch) {
        table.put(puts.asJava)
        puts.clear()
      }
    })
    if (puts.nonEmpty) {
      table.put(puts.asJava)
      puts.clear()
    }
    table.close()
  })
}
```

The caveat is that this method only uses the HBase timestamp in it's default behavior, so it will have to be extended to include providing your own timestamp. Essentially, just make the `TV` type into a `Map[Long, TV]`, and add the appropriate additional nested loop.

The `HBaseData` type is a `case class` with several of implicit methods to convert from the most common types to an `Array[Byte]` for efficient HBase storage.

The `getHbase` method ensures only one connection to HBase from each partition, to avoid connecting/disconnecting for every record.

Hopefully this is all sensible, as I implemented this as a beginner in generics.

Comment: Thanks for the useful code. Regarding your nodte "The getHbase method ensures only one connection to HBase from each partition, to avoid connecting/disconnecting for every record." -- do you have an equivalent of how to achieve this in Java? With the HBase-Spark connector?

Comment: If you look closely, the `HBase` object has a private `Option[Connection]`. The `getHbase` method checks if a `Connection` object has already been created and stored in the `Option` and returns it, otherwise it creates a new one and stores it. This should only be done from within the context of a `foreachPartition`, as the live connection cannot be serialized to be sent to the executors. Within the context of the `foreachPartition`, each executor has it's own copy of the `HBase` object, therefore, it's own connection, which is shared as you iterate over the records in the partition.

Comment: It is written in such a way that it could be each *executor* not just each *partition* has a single connection, but I've not dug deep enough into the spark internals to know if that's the case or not. I've not used spark with Java, nor have I used the HBase-Spark connector.

Comment: I see what you mean. In the Java Hbase-Spark connector, forEachPartition has its own Connection object passed to it from the outer Master program, but I have some doubts as to whether that Connection actually gets recycled. Maybe this is a better way to do this. I will give it a try and see which way is more robust. Thanks!